# JS/JQuery getting value of key in a multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I feel like one of the things really holding me back in my abilities is having an understanding of how to use arrays and objects effectively. I get the basics, but when it comes to needing a specific key and value in a complex object, i get lost. So in this example I am getting an object from **openweathermap**. The object looks like this:

```
{
    "coord":{
        "lon":-83.15,
        "lat":41.51
    },
    "weather":[
        {
            "id":721,
            "main":"Haze",
            "description":"haze",
            "icon":"50d"
        }
    ],
    "base":"cmc stations",
    "main":{
        "temp":287.05,
        "pressure":1024,
        "humidity":47,
        "temp_min":286.15,
        "temp_max":288.15
    },
    "wind":{
        "speed":5.1,
        "deg":50,
        "gust":9.3
    },
    "clouds":{
        "all":40
    },
    "dt":1443728852,
    "sys":{
        "type":1,
        "id":1435,
        "message":0.0115,
        "country":"US",
        "sunrise":1443699000,
        "sunset":1443741203
    },
    "id":5165215,
    "name":"Oak Harbor",
    "cod":200
}
```

I understand how to iterate across an array using **each()**

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=43452,us&APPID=6c62bbbc17614bb4c0cae3095e0b5a89", function(obj) {
    $.each(obj.main, function(key, val) {
        //do something//
    });
});
```

but what if I want to access something deeper in the object like say i specifically want the temperature value *for example* and then assign it to a global variable to use outside the script. I suppose less of needing a specific solution, but more of a good solid explanation on how to use a somewhat complex object like this.

Thanks for your help!

so i now have this, but the value is not being passed out of the function?

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=43452,us&APPID=6c62bbbc17614bb4c0cae3095e0b5a89", function(obj) {
    currentTemp = (obj.main.temp * 9/5 - 459.67);
    alert(currentTemp);
});

alert(currentTemp);
```

Comment: an object is like a dictionary if you need something specific just address it by its key like `obj.main.temp`, generally you would use an array if you were doing something with the same object, although you can use it with different objects in it. It really just depends on what your using it for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=43452,us&APPID=6c62bbbc17614bb4c0cae3095e0b5a89", function(obj) {
    $.each(obj.main, function(key, val) {
        if(val.temp)
        {
            // do what you want with the temperature
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go like:

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=43452,us&APPID=6c62bbbc17614bb4c0cae3095e0b5a89", function(obj) {
    $.each(obj.main, function(key, val) {
        your_global_var = val.temp;
    });
});
```

or in case you want to get more info.

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=43452,us&APPID=6c62bbbc17614bb4c0cae3095e0b5a89", function(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        your_global_var = val.main.temp;
    });
});
```

Anyway, I don't see the need for a `$.each` loop, cuz you can go like this:

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=43452,us&APPID=6c62bbbc17614bb4c0cae3095e0b5a89", function(obj) {
        your_global_var = obj.main.temp;
});
```

Comment: so without the each loop say $.obj, function(key, val) {} without the each?

Comment: no, I mean obj.main.temp insine the function(obj){}